# getting error after checkout a new branch in Laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, composer-php

I am working on Laravel project.
I checkout new branch and it gives error "
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Class 'Pimple' not found
"
it display the error file as 'elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Common/DICBuilder.php'
I run composer update,composer self-update and composer dumpautoload and it wasn't help.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is 'Pimple' a custom class?

Comment: No, Pimple is a small dependency injection container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove dir `vendor/elasticsearch` and then run `composer update`. If you still get error, then package `elasticsearch/elasticsearch` is broken. You can remove package from your project in `composer.json`.